# eval() not working?

Tags: php, eval

I'm trying to get the focal length from an image's EXIF data via PHP.

This is the code I've got so far:

```
$exif = exif_read_data("$photo");
$length10 = $exif['FocalLength'];
$length = eval($length10);
```

$length10 in this case returns something like "1050/10" for 105mm.  I don't know why.  All I want to do is have PHP do the math to return 105.  When I run this, though, I get the following error message:

```
[04-Nov-2012 20:06:39] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in index.php(52) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `1050/10` is *not valid PHP*.  It has no terminating `;` to end the statement, and results in a syntax error.

```
php > eval("1050/10");
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in php shell code(1) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Rather than `eval()` it (which technically is dangerous since you're effectively processing *user input* even if it comes from EXIF), it is recommended to split on the `/` or capture the operands with a regular expression and then perform the operation yourself.

```
// Test if the value matches the division pattern
if (preg_match('~^(\d+)/(\d+)$~', $length10, $operands)) {
  // Following a successful match, $operands is an array 
  // containing the full matched string and the two numbers captured
  // in indices [1],[2]

  // Watch for div by zero!
  if ($matches[2] !== 0) {
    echo $operands[1] / $operands[2];
  }
}
else {
  echo $length10;
}
```

Comment: The images are mine only.  There is no user input.  Can I just add a ; to the end of the string?

Comment: @NaOH The `;` will make it valid PHP and the statement will `eval()`. Officially, I do not advocate doing that unless you at least match it against the regular expression to validate the format.

Comment: So the suggestion is to never use eval() ever?

Comment: @NaOH Officially, yes, never use it if there is an alternative.  In this case, validating the input with `preg_match()` will make sure it is safe and you could use it _against my on-the-record recommendation_.